# Python VIRT Memory Usage

Tags: python, memory

I have an python application in production (on CentOS 6.2 / Python 2.6.6) that takes up to:

> 800M VIRT / 15M RES / 2M SHR

The same app run on (Fedora 16 / Python 2.7.2) "only" takes up to:

> 56M VIRT / 15M RES / 2M SHR

Is it an issue ?
What's the explanation of this difference ?
I'm wondering if it could go wrong anytime with such an amount of virtual memory ?

Answer (score 0):

What does the application do? What libraries does it use? What else is different between those machines? It's hard to give a general answer.

The VIRT value indicates how much memory the process has requested from the operating system in one way or another. But Linux is lazy in this respect: that memory won't actually be allocated to the process until the process tries to do something with it.

The RES value indicates how much memory is actually resident in RAM and currently in use by the process. This excludes pages that haven't yet been touched by the process or that have been swapped out to disk. Since the RES values are small and identical for both of those processes, there's probably nothing to worry about.

Answer (score -2):

@RaphDG
in top command if you see VIRT showing something as below

```
top
top - 10:11:51 up 38 days,  8:51,  2 users,  load average: 0.91, 0.99, 1.02
Tasks: 907 total,   1 running, 906 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 17.7%us,  5.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 70.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  6.2%si, 0.0%st
Mem:  264493616k total, 249584324k used, 14909292k free,   147780k buffers
Swap: 33554428k total,        0k used, 33554428k free, 230646508k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 4152 root  20   0 54.0g 5.5g  93m S 854.5  2.2  11863:55 java
20112 root  20   0 3234m 123m  11m S 29.6  0.0   0:42.23 java
59917 root  20   0 6691m 841m 5308 S  2.6  0.3 562:21.06 java
 8494 root  20   0 17788 1940  952 R  1.0  0.0   0:18.95 top
```

g is Gigabit and m is Megabit (not byte). 800 Megabit is only 100Megabyte

@RaphDG

It seems that version, top 3.3.10, has got rid of showing these values in g, m or G.
Please install top new version (3.3.10) and it would show you the values in KiB and where it is not being shown in suffix, the value should be considered in KiB (in VIRT column.)
Search to convert KiB to Gigabyte on web and convert it.

top -version
  procps-ng version 3.3.10
Usage:
  top -hv | -bcHiOSs -d secs -n max -u|U user -p pid(s) -o field -w [cols]

top
top - 15:39:20 up 139 days, 23:58,  1 user,  load average: 1.86, 2.16, 2.23
Tasks: 107 total,   3 running, 104 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 60.0%us, 34.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  5.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si, 0.0%st

KiB Mem :  3883016 total,   276344 free,  2766720 used,   839952 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   630780 total,   586468 free,    44312 used.   610484 avail Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0 200:30.37 rcu_sched